# Twitter Desktop Client Authentication

Tags: clojure, twitter-oauth

I'm using [clj-oauth](https://github.com/mattrepl/clj-oauth) for a school project where I am creating a desktop client that reads from Twitter. I've been attempting to authenticate the [client against Twitter](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554643/Authentication) and get the PIN so I can set it in the client and forget about it (since this is only for personal use and doesn't need to be distributed). It seems to me that after I request the token, I should be able to print the result from this:

```
(oauth/user-approval-uri consumer 
                         request-token)
```

And then use the URI printed to authenticate. However, whenever I try to paste that URI into my browser, Twitter gives me an error, saying that someone has already used the token I have provided. I have already correctly provided all the values to create a consumer and then obtain a request-token.

Is there an easy way to get my PIN using just the CLI and my browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran across the same issue with this library.  There is a minor bug in the user-approval-uri.

You can find the fix on my fork https://github.com/kurtharriger/clj-oauth.

The query string should have only included the oauth_token but was writing the entire map, for a quick one time fix you can probably just manually remove the extra bits from the query string when pasting in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive, but I think you need to get an access-token after you get a request-token. Some of it is explained [here](http://kovshenin.com/archives/twitter-api-pin-based-oauth-php/).

> "Pin based Twitter OAuth works just like the original (web) OAuth (request tokens, access tokens) but instead of returning back to a web page, Twitter gives out a Pin code that you have to input into your app in order to exchange its request token with an access token."

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Waffle - I understand that you get a pin, but if you look at [this Java-based example](https://github.com/kaeppler/signpost-examples/blob/master/OAuthTwitterExample/src/TwitterMain.java), you can see that it directs the user to a web page to retrieve a pin. My problem is that my webpage is giving me an error about my authentication being faulty.

Comment: Well, as far as I can tell from the chart at http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#anchor9 you essentially need to get the access token. Because you are making a desktop client and it is a single user application there is a way of just obtaining that token from Twitter. If you register the application on http://dev.twitter.com/apps you can actually click on "My Access Token" on the side bar once it is registered. That is your unique token which I presume can be placed right into the application. It is explained here: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_single_token